# Proof of a limit formula

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-writing

If $h(x) = f(x)/g(x)$

$lim(x->b) f(x) = L$

$lim(x->b) g(x) = M$

Prove that $lim(x->b) h(x) = L/M$

Sorry for the terrible latex. ONLY FORMAL PROOFS!

For every $\epsilon > 0$

Since $lim(x->b) f(x) = L$ therefore, $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $|x - b| < \delta_1$

Since $lim(x->b) g(x) = M$ therefore, $|g(x) - M| < \epsilon$ for $|x - b| < \delta_2$

So if $|x - b| < \delta$ we can have **BOTH,** $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ and $|g(x) - L| < \epsilon$

Therefore, Let $\delta = \text{min}(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ $\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(1)$

Finally, we have by agreement $(1)$ we have the following:

$|x - b| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon \space\space\space \& \space\space\space |g(x) - M| < \epsilon$

Ideas after this?

Comment: Do you mean $h(x)=f(x)/g(x)?$

Comment: @mfl, yes, how can we edit that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay into answering. Moreover you can improve lim by writing \lim_{x\to a} f(x) into $\$$'s

Answer (score 0):

Question: There's a bit of incongruity with $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to b}h(x) = L/M$. I'm assuming you meant L+M below. Disregard this answer if I happen to be wrong.

Hint: First, fix an $\epsilon$ (basically, in the beginning of your proof, say "Let $\epsilon > 0$"). Then use your existing limit definitions on $\epsilon/2$ instead of $\epsilon$. Then use the Triangle Inequality:
$$
 |a + b| \leq |a| + |b| \hspace{8pt} \forall a,b
$$

Good luck!